# Passing different values under the <option> tag in HTML select drop box

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Beginner trying my best!

Objective: A drop down box allowing customers to select a choice (number of rooms). Their selected choice would then populate a cost (quote) in two seperate locations. The first as a monthly cost and the second as a yearly cost.

Therefore, I need to pass a different value to the boxes, since one will display a monthly and one yearly result.

Can anyone help, I can only populate one result so far.

Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunction() {
       var x = document.getElementById("rooms").value;
       document.getElementById("monthlycost").innerHTML =  x;
       

}
```

```html
<select id="rooms" onchange="myFunction()">

      <option value="">-- Select Number --</option>
      <option value="3,500"> 1-15
      <option value="4,500"> 16-30
      <option value="5,000"> 31-50
      <option value="5,500"> 51-75
      <option value="6,500"> 76-100
      <option value="8,000"> 101-125
      <option value="9,500"> 126-150
      </select>
      
      <p id="monthlycost"></p>
```

Comment: One way would be to store the values in some format like ```cost1:cost2``` and then do string manipulation using regexp's. Another way would be to use some made-up attributes (but I don't recommend it) and get their values from ```rooms.options[rooms.selectedIndex]```. I'm sure though there are some better solutions.

Comment: @P.Sav, Currently the displayed value in <p id="demo"></p> is monthly amount. Right? You want to display the yearly amount for the corresponding selected monthly data?

Comment: you can use array that contain object has monthly and yearly cost. And value of option is the index.

Comment: @vijesh I think he wants to have all options with 2 values and display them in different <p>'s. Am I right, @P.Sav?

Comment: @vijesh Yes that is correct. I want to display the yearly amount in a separate location. So when a customer selects the choice, they are automatically displayed with the monthly and yearly costs.

Comment: @StefanOctavian Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to say, you also want to show year data based on selected monthly package, simply you can multiply with total months of year. Here is the snippet, first one shows monthly data & second one will show yearly data based on selected monthly data:

```js
function myFunction() {
       var x = document.getElementById("rooms").value;
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x;
       document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML =  parseInt(x.replace(/[,.]/g , '')) * 12;
}
```

```html
<select id="rooms" onchange="myFunction()">

      <option value="">-- Select Number --</option>
      <option value="3,500"> 1-15
      <option value="4,500"> 16-30
      <option value="5,000"> 31-50
      <option value="5,500"> 51-75
      <option value="6,500"> 76-100
      <option value="8,000"> 101-125
      <option value="9,500"> 126-150
      </select>
      
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <p id="demo1"></p>
```

Comment: This is the result i was looking for,  however the yearly figures do not follow a strict calculation format. For example: 
Yearly Cost: 35,0000 - Rooms:  1-15
 Yearly cost: 40,00 - Rooms:16-30
 Yearly cost: 45,000 - Rooms: 31-50
Yearly cost: 50,000 - Rooms: 51-75
Yearly cost: 65,000 - Rooms: 76-100
Yearly cost: 80,000 - Rooms: 101-125
Yearly cost: 95,000 - Rooms: 126-150

Comment: @P.Sav Is my calculation wrong? and you want the exact calculation showed in your comment?

Comment: Hi Nik, thanks very much. Calculation is correct, I didn't look correctly at your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change your function and add  `<p id="demoYear"></p>` on your html

```
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("rooms").value;
 document.getElementById("monthlycost").innerHTML =  x;
 var str = x;
 str = str.replace(/,/g, "");
  document.getElementById("demoYear").innerHTML = parseInt(str, 10)*12;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

<select id="rooms" onchange="myFunction()">

      <option value="">-- Select Number --</option>
      <option value="3,500"> 1-15
      <option value="4,500"> 16-30
      <option value="5,000"> 31-50
      <option value="5,500"> 51-75
      <option value="6,500"> 76-100
      <option value="8,000"> 101-125
      <option value="9,500"> 126-150
      </select>

      <p id="demo"></p>
      <p id="demoYear"></p>
```

Comment: @P.Sav, Hope this will help

Comment: What good is in ```str = "x".replace(/,/g, "")```? Did you want to say ```str = x``` instead of ```"x"```?

Comment: Thanks very much @vijesh

Answer (score 1):

You can store prices on an global object:

```
var prices = {
    "15": {
        month: 150,
        year: 3500
    },
    "30": {
        month: 200,
        year: 4500
    }
    ...
}
```

Then get the correspondent value from combobox:

```
<select id="rooms" onchange="myFunction()">

  <option value="">-- Select Number --</option>
  <option value="15"> 1-15
  <option value="30"> 16-30
  <option value="50"> 31-50
  <option value="75"> 51-75
  <option value="100"> 76-100
  <option value="125"> 101-125
  <option value="150"> 126-150
</select>


function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("rooms").value;
   if (prices[x]) {
      var monthPrice = prices[x].month;
      var yearPrice = prices[x].year;
   }

}
```

Prices object can be recovered from different sources (ajax for example) and can store more info needed later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your dropdown client side, you can have another attribute in your dropdown like

```
<select id="leave" onchange="leaveChange(this.selectedIndex)">
  <option year="1" value="5">Get Married</option>
  <option year="2" value="10">Have a Baby</option>
  <option year="3" value="15">Adopt a Child</option>
  <option year="4" value="20">Retire</option>
  <option year="5" value="25">Military Leave</option>
  <option year="6" value="30">Medical Leave</option>
</select>

<div id="message"></div>
<div id="year"></div>

<script>
function leaveChange(index) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =      
    document.getElementById("leave").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("leave");
    var y = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('year');
    document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = y;
  }
</script>
```